# When seconds come x, do something

Tags: javascript, time

How I will do that:
When seconds come 31 (example 11:57 31sec.) do somthing, every minute. Using Javasript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how to "listen" the seconds I think.

Comment: May I ask why you need such a specific interval?

Comment: To learn the online visitor numbers at a spesific time. Such as visitor numbers at 1,11,21,...,51.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the current time, calculate the number of seconds until the next time the seconds is ':31' then use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) with the appropriate delay. You could use something like this:

```
var atSeconds = 31;
var secondsLeft = atSeconds - new Date().getSeconds();
if (secondsLeft <= 0) secondsLeft += 60;
setTimeout(foo, secondsLeft * 1000);
```

Remember to call it again in the function `foo` so that it repeats.

Comment: Somehow I doubt you would be able to reach such precision with JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe setInterval instead, to do it every minute.

Comment: I would have to recommend passing a string to setTimeout.

Comment: setInterval would probably also work, although I'm not sure how much accuracy setInterval guarantees if left running for a long time. If each call is a fraction of a second too late, that error could build up over time.

Comment: Hmm, you are definitely right. Using this method you can correct any error over time.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will probably be as close as you can get.

```
function initializeInterval() {
    while (new Date().getSeconds() < 30);
    setInterval(doWork, 60000);
}

function doWork() {

}
```